# Not able to pass parameters through url in Ajax request using Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to pass a parameter through a url in an Ajax request that's triggered by a confirmation dialogue. I'd like to fetch the value of that parameter in my Rails controller given a successful request but I haven't  been able to do it.

**I've tried so far the following code:**

**Here my Ajax request where I've been adding the param in the URL plus other params in data**

```
function continueSave() {
  var name = $('#leader_name').val();
  var persisted_time = $('#leader_time').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/leaderboards/1/?test=1",
    data: { leader: { name: name, time: time } },
    success: success

  });
}
```

**Here the dialogue-related JS**

```
function nameAlert() {
  return confirm("Name already exists. Would you like to continue?");
};

(function() {
  if (nameAlert()) {
    continueSave();
  }
else {
    //something else here
   }
})();
```

Although the request successfully reaches the controller there's params[:test] is nil in the controller.

I've also tried to pass the test param in data, but it is not working either.

Would appreciate some help.

**The relevant controller action (leaders_controller.rb)**

```
  def create
    @leader = Leader.new(leader_params)
    @leader.leaderboard_id = @leaderboard.id
    @name_repeated = !@leaderboard.leaders.find_by(name: @leader.name).nil?
    @check = params[:test]

     if params[:test].nil? && @name_repeated == true
       render :template => 'leaders/repeated_name.js.erb'
     else
      @leader.save
      @rank = @leader.rank_in(@leaderboard)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @leader.save
          format.html { redirect_to root_path }
          format.js { }
        else
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Note:
1.- 'leaders/repeated_name.js.erb' contains the code for the Ajax request
2.- In routes Leader resource is nested within Leaderboard resource

Comment: try with request headers -

headers : {
            "Accept" : "application/json",
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        }

Comment: Thanks Ruben. I've just started to experiment with Ajax so I'm afraid I wouldn't even know how to do that. If you have a couple of minutes to spare could you provide further guidance?

Comment: you just need to add that property to your request object: $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/leaderboards/1/?test=1",
    headers : { "Accept" : "application/json", "Content-Type" : "application/json" },
    data: { leader: { name: name, time: time } },
    success: success

  });

Comment: Maybe you can use `type: "GET"` and pass all your data by `GET`? Show us your controller code related to this, please.

Comment: Thanks Ruben I've tried the headers but had the same result. Post request goes through but no params in url. 

Oskar I've posted the relevant bit of my controller as requested. The GET request wouldn't go through since I'm posting data, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys I found the mistake. It was a dumb one. 
I have shallow nested routes so that leaders is nested in leaderboards, therefore I was using the incorrect path for the request. It should be:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/leaderboards/1/leaders?test=1",
    data: { leader: { name: name, time: time } },
    success: success

  });
```

I should have caught that before sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post here - my comments are getting too long.

Try adding `{ type: 1}` to your `data` and changing `type` to `GET`. Rails `params` contain both `GET` and `POST` data - you don't even have to change your controller.

```
function continueSave() {
    var name = $('#leader_name').val();
    var persisted_time = $('#leader_time').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/leaderboards/1/",
        data: { leader: { name: name, time: time }, test: 1 },
        success: success
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Oskar, thanks I just tried that without success. I'll give it a second try

Comment: Actually Oskar I just noticed the request is not going through even without the param in the URL. I checked if it was reaching the controller with Pry and was  sure it was reaching the controller, but maybe I was wrong. Could you see any issues with the request even without the test param